# jQuery get id of element by searching for it by class

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-traversing

This is my html :

```
<div id="my_box_one" class="head-div">
   <div>
       <div class="some_box">a</div>
       <div class="some_box">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the ID of the parent div("#my_box_one") using the class of that div(".head-div")

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".some_box").click(function(){
   var abc = $(this).parentsUntil(".head-div").attr("id");
   // also tried $(this).parent(".head-div") -- same effect
   alert(abc); // Shows as Undefined
});   

});
```

I can do the following and it will work okay, but it doesn't seem right.

```
var abc = $(this).parent("div").parent("div").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use **.closest( selector )**, for example:

```
var abc = $(this).closest(".head-div").attr("id");
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

**.parent( selector )** selects only immediate parent of the element.

Answer (score 5):

`parentsUntil` gets all the parent elements until the one matched by the selector.  It does not include the element matched.  You're trying to get the `id` of the intervening `div`, which is obviously undefined.

You need to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), which goes up the DOM tree until it finds an element matching the selector, then returns *only* that element:

```
var abc = $(this).closest(".head-div").attr("id");
```

---

Edit: for extra speed, but less flexibility in the event that you change your markup, you could use the `parentNode` property:

```
var abc = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
```