# Get Parent div id in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i get Parent Div id of component.

I have already referred this link but its not working.

[jQuery get id of element by searching for it by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841650/jquery-get-id-of-element-by-searching-for-it-by-class)

Here Is my Sample Code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function linkClickEvent()
            {
                alert ($(this).parent().attr('id')); //Gives Me Undefined
                alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id')); //Gives Me Undefined
                alert($(this).parent().attr('id')); //Gives Me Undefined
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container_1">
            <a href="#" onclick="linkClickEvent();" id="link_1">Container_1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="container_2">
            <a href="#" onclick="linkClickEvent();" id="link_2">Container_2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="container_3">
            <a href="#" onclick="linkClickEvent();" id="link_3">Container_3</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your onclick event, in onclick event function `linkClickEvent` pass current element reference using `this` :

```
 <a href="#" onclick="linkClickEvent(this);" id="link_1">Container_1</a>
```

and in function add parameter to accept element reference:

```
function linkClickEvent (element) {
    console.log($(element).closest("div").attr("id"));
}
```

Comment: @Rush.2707 check your console of browser dev tools for errors

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because you are using `on*` attributes to  hook up your events, `this` refers to the `window`, not the clicked element. Use jQuery to hook up your events:

```
<div id="container_1">
    <a href="#" id="link_1">Container_1</a>
</div>
<div id="container_2">
    <a href="#" id="link_2">Container_2</a>
</div>
<div id="container_3">
    <a href="#" id="link_3">Container_3</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('div a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parentId = $(this).closest('div').prop('id');
    alert(parentId);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QCUjv/)

Answer (score 1):

You should do event handling in your JS files. Separating content, style and behaviour really *is* best practice.

You can get your element via:

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){/*...*/});
```

And then save the id of the attribute clicked via:

```
var parent_id = $(this).parents('.classOfParent').attr('id');
```

or

```
var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Also, if in doubt, check what "this" is with console.log() which works WAY better than alert().

Edit: Revised your question. Sorry, now it's correct.

PS: [Why is console.log() considered better than alert()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert)

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()`;

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.ready instead of onclick attribute.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                alert(id);
            });
        });
```